# Determining the structure of the abelian group, integral matrix

Tags: group-theory, matrices, abelian-groups

I am revising for my upcoming university exams and I have a past exam question that I am finding particularly challenging...

a) Consider the integral matrix

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 2 & 4 & 2\\
    4 & 4 & 8 & 5\\
    6 & 12 & 12 & 8\\
    4 & 10 & 8 & 6\\\end{bmatrix}$$

Determine the structure of the abelian group given by generators and relations

$$A_R := \langle a_1,a_2,a_3,a_4 \mid R.a=0 \rangle$$

b) Determine the number of elements of order 2 in $A_R$.

Any help with this would be very much appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can do $\Bbb Z^n/R\Bbb Z^n\cong \Bbb Z^n/D\Bbb Z^n$ with $D$ diagonal via Smith Normal Form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know that invertible matrix operations do not change the range of the matrix, thus
$$A_R = \mathrm{cok}(R \colon \mathbb Z^4 \to \mathbb Z^4)$$ remains the same.
Subtract row one once from row two and four and twice from row three. You end up with the matrix
$$
  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 4 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 6 & 6 & 0 & 2 \\ 4 & 6 & 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}
$$
Now you make the obvious column operations to end up with

$$
  \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 6 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
The result is clearly
$$
  A_R = \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/2 \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/6\mathbb Z
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot this is very helpful, could you please explain to me the "cok" notation, thanks again for the help!!

Comment: Sure. There are several levels of insight. As a first step, you may view it as a short hand for $\mathbb Z^4 / \mathrm{im} R$, where $R$ is the homomorphism associated to the matrix $A_R$. If you are used to some notions of category theory, you may understand it by its universal property as a special a colimit. This is useful to make the similarities between several categories (like Modules, Algebras and everything that has enought 'commutative structure') precise. Here the notion of abelian category the right concept.

Comment: 4 years late to the party, I am trying to understand where the $\mathbb{Z}$ in $A_R\simeq \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_6$ came from while comparing to my notes. Am I correct in thinking that it is because there are 4 generators and 3 zeros on the main diagonal? For a moment I thought it might be because of the 1 in the fourth column but it seems that the one in the fourth column would give rise to a phantom $\times \{e\}$. Thanks!